# How to prompt user for a target host in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to write a bootstrapper playbook for new machines in Ansible which will reconfigure the network settings. At the time of the first execution target machines will have DHCP-assigned address.

The user who is supposed to execute the playbook knows the assigned IP address of a new machine. I would like to prompt the user for is value.

`vars_prompt` module allows getting input from the user, however it is defined under `hosts` section effectively preventing host address as the required value.

Is it possible without using a wrapper script modifying inventory file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The right way to do this is to create a dynamic host with add_host and place it in a new group, then start a new play that targets that group. That way, if you have other connection vars that need to be set ahead of time (credentials/keys/etc) you could set them on an empty group in inventory, then add the host to it dynamically. For example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: please enter the target host IP
    private: no
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ target_host }}"
        groups: dynamically_created_hosts

- hosts: dynamically_created_hosts
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="do things on target host here"
```

Comment: What happens if you keep running the same playbook with exactly the same IP as input? Does it keep adding IPs to a file somewhere, or the `dynamically_created_hosts` get's cleared at the end of the execution? In other words, is `dynamically_created_hosts` persisted?

Answer (score 8):

You could pass it with [`extra-vars`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) instead.

Simply make your `hosts` section a variable such as `{{ hosts_prompt }}` and then pass the host on the command line like so:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/environment playbook.yml --extra-vars "hosts_prompt=192.168.1.10"
```

Or if you are using the [default inventory file location](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#id4) of `/etc/ansible/hosts` you could simply use:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars "hosts_prompt=192.168.1.10"
```

Comment: The `inventory/environment` part is just an example (as with `playbook.yml`). If you don't provide an inventory file with `-i` then Ansible will simply pick up the default inventory file `/etc/ansible/hosts` which is not normally what you want even when you are specifying the hosts using `extra-vars`

Comment: It's an example about how to pass `extra-vars`, not a "here's the exact line you need to type". And an inventory _is_ a necessary argument, it just defaults to `/etc/ansible/hosts` and if that file doesn't exist then it will fail.

Comment: @techraf: Your suggested edits were rejected in the review queue. ydaetskcoR has nothing to do with that. Edits like that are simply not accepted on SO. Since this answer _does_ currently provide the answer for you, you really should accept it, for future visitors' sake.

Comment: Your answer was deleted because it was a copy-paste of this one. Plagiarism like that is not allowed on SO. The OP of this answer now added your specific case to the answer, so I really see no reason not to accept this one.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Matt's answer for multiple hosts.

input example would be `192.0.2.10,192.0.2.11`

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: please enter the target host IP
    private: no
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: dynamically_created_hosts
      with_items: "{{ target_host.split(',') }}"


- hosts: dynamically_created_hosts
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="do things on target host here"
```

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Disclaimer: [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36605054/2947502) offers the best solution to the problem. While this one is working it is based on a hack and I leave it as a reference.</sup>

I found out it was possible use a currently undocumented [hack](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/RuntoPUvqHM) (credit to [Bruce P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33334963/2947502) for pointing me to the post) that turns the value of `-i` / `--inventory` parameter into an ad hoc list of hosts ([reference](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/kiZdBh0FplQ/sVrf7wVTDwAJ)). With just the hostname/ip address and a trailing space (like below) it refers to a single host without the need for the inventory file to exist.

Command:

```
ansible-playbook -i "192.168.1.21," playbook.yml
```

And accordingly `playbook.yml` can be run against all hosts (which in the above example will be equal to a single host `192.168.1.21`):

```
- hosts: all
```

The list might contain more than one ip address `-i "192.168.1.21,192.168.1.22"`

Comment: I don't like this approach because if someone runs the playbook without parameters by mistake the **hell breaks loose**.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jacob's and Matt's examples, with the inclusion of a username and password prompt:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
    - name: verify_ansible_version
      assert:
        that: "ansible_version.full is version_compare('2.10.7', '>=')"
        msg: "Error: You must update Ansible to at least version 2.10.7 to run this playbook..."
  vars_prompt:
    - name: target_hosts
      prompt: |
        Enter Target Host IP[s] or Hostname[s] (comma separated)
        (example: 1.1.1.1,myhost.example.com)
      private: false
    - name: username
      prompt: Enter Target Host[s] Login Username
      private: false
    - name: password
      prompt: Enter Target Host[s] Login Password
      private: true
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: host_groups
      with_items:
        - "{{ target_hosts.split(',') }}"
    - add_host:
        name: login
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
- hosts: host_groups
  remote_user: "{{ hostvars['login']['username'] }}"
  vars:
    ansible_password: "{{ hostvars['login']['password'] }}"
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: sudo
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ hostvars['login']['password'] }}"
  roles:
    - my_role
```