# Does /etc/ansible/hosts need to be manually created for Ansible on the Mac?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

According to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html

> Once running the env-setup script you’ll be running from checkout and the default inventory file will be /etc/ansible/hosts.

Do I need to create an `/etc/ansible/hosts` file?

And right below this there's a warning:

> Note
>   ANSIBLE_INVENTORY is available starting at 1.9 and substitutes the deprecated > ANSIBLE_HOSTS

So, am I supposed to be using an alternative to the hosts file?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to create an `/etc/ansible/hosts` file?

Technically speaking this file, in this path, is not required for Ansible to run.

The [inventory file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html), as it is called, is required, but it can be placed elsewhere on the filesystem and is path referenced in the command line (`-i`), in `ansible.cfg` file (either in your home or current directory), or environment variable (`ANSIBLE_INVENTORY`).

Ansible coming from Homebrew on OS X places the file in `/usr/local/etc/ansible` to allow regular user to modify the files without giving the account write permissions under the `/etc` branch.

You might even use [an undocumented trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317628/how-does-inventory-option-in-ansible-work-when-it-is-given-value-with-a-traili) which allows Ansible to be run against an ad-hoc created list of servers.

> > Note ANSIBLE_INVENTORY is available starting at 1.9 and substitutes the deprecated ANSIBLE_HOSTS
>
> So, am I supposed to be using an alternative to the hosts file?

This notice means the name of the environment variable pointing to the inventory file. It is not "*an alternative to the hosts file*", it is *an alternative to the ANSIBLE_HOSTS variable*.

There is [a comment in the source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1ecf51d87e90e877cce387c738f1496eba2da93c/lib/ansible/constants.py#L145) indicating the reason for change was confusing naming.

Ansible community started to refer to the file containing host and group definitions as "hosts file", but as it has different structure to the system hosts fleet, a new name "inventory" was implemented. Still some references (like the default filename) exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
You will need to create the /etc/ansible/hosts file.

If you create a file anywhere else you can either use `ANSIBLE_HOSTS` or you can use the `-i` switch when calling ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create hosts file manually.
`/etc/ansible/hosts` is the default one.
You may create file anywhere you like and use `ANSIBLE_HOSTS` environment variable to point to your file.
Also you may want to use `ansible.cfg` file and set path to your hosts file there.